# Silex htaccess regex block all pages except one

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, silex

What i'm trying to achieve:

**example.com/payment** - can be accessed from anywhere.
While everything else can only be accessed from certain ip.

I'm using silex 2 and apache 2.4. In case you don't know, silex uses controllers and routing, so there are no direct .php files, in this case (payment.php)

here's my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
##Allow profiler to be accessed from office only
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.111\.111\.111
RewriteRule ^(.*)_profiler(.*)$ https://www.example.com [R=301,L]

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=ENVIRONMENT:prod]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^stage.
RewriteRule .* - [E=ENVIRONMENT:stage]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} .dev$ [OR]
RewriteRule .* - [E=ENVIRONMENT:dev]

### PROD ###
##force www and https
RewriteCond %{ENV:ENVIRONMENT} prod
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

### STAGE ###
##force https
RewriteCond %{ENV:ENVIRONMENT} stage
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^stage\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://stage.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
##deny access
RewriteCond %{ENV:ENVIRONMENT} stage
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.111\.111\.111
RewriteRule ^((?!payment).)*$ https://stage.example.com [R=403,L]

### DEV ###
</IfModule>
```

The important part is the last few lines with **##deny access** for stage.

I've been pulling my hair out for the past few hours and i can't seem to get this to work. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out here.

Have a nice day ! :)

Comment: I am here for the regex tag, no knowledge on the others. Can you give more details on what you want to achieve? E.g. describe in prose what the regex is supposed to match/not match. Can you give sample input which should match and which should not match? For those of us who know regexes, but not the other tags, what flavor of regex is needed; or give a spec/examples of working regexes. Also describe the way your experiments fail.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly.
I think the regex is fine - `^((?!payment).)*$` 
If url contains word 'payment' (e.g. example.com/payment ) it should not match. And that's what it does. So i don't think the problem is here. It's probably in the RewriteRule part.

Comment: 1. the `^((?!payment).)*$` is very expensive, so try `!^payment$` instead. 2 most likely it will never get `/payment` since it changes to `/index.php`. So better to check `%{THE_REQUEST}` with `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\h/payment`\n`RewriteRule ^ https://stage.example.com [R=403,L]`

Comment: Yeap, the RewriteCond works with the request, thanks a lot ! but i don't understand what the \h part means, isn't that just escaped 'h' character ? what's it for ? 
Also, ```!^payment$``` doesn't match anything.

Comment: \n means new line since comments are not multiline here. `\h` in the regexp means horizontal space symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that you only want your last part to be fixed? The `##deny access` lines? If not, I will expand my answer to what is needed ;)

```
##deny access for everything but /payment from IP != 11.111.111.111
RewriteCond %{ENV:ENVIRONMENT} stage
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.111\.111\.111
RewriteRule !^/payment$ - [F]
```

If you need `/payment` to be rewritten to `stage.example.com` add this

```
##allow access to /payment
RewriteCond %{ENV:ENVIRONMENT} stage
RewriteRule ^/payment$ https://stage.example.com [R=301,L]
```